# Show loader wait for file load

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, css

I am using ajax request to get the file.
The loader is working fine based on ajax request, but file size is too large. I like to show a preloader until the loading of the file has completed.

Comment: Is the simplest way to show div with <img> which is loader.gif. When you start ajax you show this div, when success or error hide it.

Comment: I'd use a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and then while the promise is pending show the loader and when the promise resolves hide the loader and show the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can show some loading GIF when process starts. And when completed hide the GIF.

```
$('#loader_image').show();
$.ajax({
      ...
      complete: function(){
        $('#loader_image').hide();
      }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you should have a element with a loading image ( or anything to show waiting ) and set style to  display:none  when user   click on button to fire a ajax call you first set this element to show

```
$.ajax({
 url: "test.html",
context: document.body
}).done(function() {
$( this ).hide( ".loader" ); // this line run when ajax call completely then loader element should be hide 
});
```